# If accordion is append() after document.ready() than it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added a button that appends accordion but the problem is they don't seem to be working. I'm not sure how to fix this. If accordion html append's after document.ready() than the accordion doesn't work. Can someone help me fix this problem?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#insertAcc").click(function() {
            $("#TheDiv").append('<ul id="MainAcc1" class="accordion"> <li class="open"> <div class="link"> <i id="CloseMainAcc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove GlyphiconRemove"></i> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div> <div class="submenu"> <p>Body</p> </div> </li> </ul>');
          });

          $(function() {
            var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
              this.el = el || {};
              this.multiple = multiple || true;

              var links = this.el.find('.link');
              links.on('click', {
                el: this.el,
                multiple: this.multiple
              }, this.dropdown)
            }

            Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
              var $el = e.data.el;
              $this = $(this),
                $next = $this.next();

              $next.slideToggle();
              $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

              if (!e.data.multiple) {
                $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
              };
            }
            var accordion = new Accordion($('.accordion'), true);
          });
          $("#CloseMainAcc").click(function() {
            $("#MainAcc1").remove();
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body style="height: 900px;">
      <button id="insertAcc">Insert Accordion</button>
      <div id="TheDiv"></div>
      <h4>If the accordion is loaded before Document.ready than they both work fine.</h4>
      <ul class="accordion">
        <li class="open">
          <div class="link"> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
          <div class="submenu">
            <p>Body</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="accordion">
        <li class="open">
          <div class="link"> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
          <div class="submenu">
            <p>Body</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <style>
        body {
          height: 400px;
        }
        
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          padding-left: 10px;
        }
        
        h1 {
          color: #595959;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: 100;
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        h1 a {
          color: #d9d9d9;
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .accordion {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        .accordion .link {
          cursor: pointer;
          display: block;
          padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
          color: #d9d9d9;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 700;
          position: relative;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        
        .accordion li:last-child .link {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
        
        .accordion li i {
          position: absolute;
          top: 16px;
          left: 12px;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #d9d9d9;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;
        }
        
        .accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
          right: 12px;
          left: auto;
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        
        .accordion li.open .link {
          color: #d9d9d9;
        }
        
        .accordion li.open i {
          color: #d9d9d9;
        }
        
        .accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        
        .accordion li.default .submenu {
          display: block;
        }
        /************ Sub Menu *************/
        
        .submenu {
          background-color: #d6d6dd;
          font-size: 14px;
        }
        
        .submenu a {
          display: block;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #d9d9d9;
          padding: 12px;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
          -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
          transition: all 0.25s ease;
        }
        
        .submenu a:hover {
          background-color: #d9d9d9;
          color: #FFF;
        }
        
        .panel-body {
          padding: 0 0 10px 0;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .TopContainer {
          background-color: #3b5998 !important;
          color: #FFF !important;
        }
        
        .GlyphiconRemove {
          color: #fff;
          float: right;
          margin-right: 25px;
          transition: all ease .5s;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        
        .GlyphiconRemove:hover {
          color: #f00;
        }
      </style>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Usually you have to compile, after you change the Dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ready the document and his elements are ready and visible for your javascript. If you append an element to the dom, the javascript was executed before on document ready. At this moment the new element was not visible for the javascript.

So you have to execute your javascript again after the element is appended. You can do this by using a function.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#insertAcc").click(function() {
        $("#TheDiv").append('<ul id="MainAcc1" class="accordion"> <li class="open"> <div class="link"> <i id="CloseMainAcc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove GlyphiconRemove"></i> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div> <div class="submenu"> <p>Body</p> </div> </li> </ul>');
        initAcc();
      });

      $(function() {
        initAcc();
      });
      $("#CloseMainAcc").click(function() {
        $("#MainAcc1").remove();
      });
    });
    
    function initAcc(){
       var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
          this.el = el || {};
          this.multiple = multiple || true;

          var links = this.el.find('.link');
          //dirty fix remove all click handlers before
          links.off('click');

          links.on('click', {
            el: this.el,
            multiple: this.multiple
          }, this.dropdown)
        }

        Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
          var $el = e.data.el;
          $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

          $next.slideToggle();
          $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

          if (!e.data.multiple) {
            $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
          };
        }
        var accordion = new Accordion($('.accordion'), true);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body style="height: 900px;">
  <button id="insertAcc">Insert Accordion</button>
  <div id="TheDiv"></div>
  <h4>If the accordion is loaded before Document.ready than they both work fine.</h4>
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li class="open">
      <div class="link"> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        <p>Body</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li class="open">
      <div class="link"> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        <p>Body</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: #595959;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    h1 a {
      color: #d9d9d9;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .accordion {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .accordion .link {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
      color: #d9d9d9;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 700;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .accordion li:last-child .link {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .accordion li i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 16px;
      left: 12px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #d9d9d9;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }
    
    .accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
      right: 12px;
      left: auto;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .accordion li.open .link {
      color: #d9d9d9;
    }
    
    .accordion li.open i {
      color: #d9d9d9;
    }
    
    .accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    
    .accordion li.default .submenu {
      display: block;
    }
    /************ Sub Menu *************/
    
    .submenu {
      background-color: #d6d6dd;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .submenu a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #d9d9d9;
      padding: 12px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
      transition: all 0.25s ease;
    }
    
    .submenu a:hover {
      background-color: #d9d9d9;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    
    .panel-body {
      padding: 0 0 10px 0;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .TopContainer {
      background-color: #3b5998 !important;
      color: #FFF !important;
    }
    
    .GlyphiconRemove {
      color: #fff;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 25px;
      transition: all ease .5s;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .GlyphiconRemove:hover {
      color: #f00;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but now the second accordion isn't working properly :S // it closes once it opens.

Comment: Now if you append more than ONE accordion, others don't seem to be working.

Comment: oh yes, now you add a click handler on ready and another on append, each time you loop the .link. You have to prevent adding click handler to links that already have one.

Comment: Thanks a LOT!~ and a lot of people will find this accordion helpful as well. also posted this on https://codepen.io/BMUZAMMIL/pen/rYZGWp

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the accordion initiation in a function:

```
function initAccordion() {
     return new Accordion($('.accordion'), true);
}
```

Then you can call `var accordion = initAccordion();` on document ready or after you added the accordion to your DOM.

Answer (score -1):

you need to move (or duplicate) this line:

```
var accordion = new Accordion($('.accordion'), true);
```

to

```
$("#insertAcc").click(function() {
    $("#TheDiv").append('<ul id="MainAcc1" class="accordion"> <li class="open"> <div class="link"> <i id="CloseMainAcc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove GlyphiconRemove"></i> Heading Number 1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </div> <div class="submenu"> <p>Body</p> </div> </li> </ul>');
    var accordion = new Accordion($('.accordion'), true);
});
```